# According to NT is wearing gold a sin against Gods Divine Law?

Tags: greek, gender

I have been reading a lot of Church Fathers and early Christian writers and they translated the Bible is opposed to women's adornment and they all said the Bible condemns all jewelry (as apparently word for jewelry doesn't exist and jewelry means gold). One of them even said that women's adornment is a mortal sin as it is against Gods Divine Law. What do you Guys think about it?

> 1 Timothy 2:9 - Likewise, I want the women to adorn themselves with
> respectable apparel, with modesty, and with self-control, not with
> braided hair or gold or pearls or expensive clothes
>
> 1 Peter 3:3 - whose adorning let not be the external, of braiding of
> hair and putting around of gold, or putting on of garments

Comment: A question needs a verse attached to it.

Comment: 1 Timothy 2 9 and 1 Peter 3 3

Answer (score 2):

The Bible is certainly not opposed to women adorning themselves in the right circumstances. Numerous times the O.T. speaks approvingly of the splendid clothes and array of jewellery brides would put on to look radiant on their wedding day (e.g. SS 1:9-10 & 7:1). Then, in the N.T. the analogy of Christ's people preparing themselves as a bride is used. John the apostle was given this vision:

> "And I John saw the holy city, New Jerusalem, coming down from God out
> of heaven, prepared as a bride adorned for her husband... the bride, the Lamb's wife." Revelation
> 21:2 & 9

This speaks of the whole number of the redeemed, those saved to be the bride of Christ. Now, if ***wearing jewels, gold, fine garments and having braided hair is okay for a bride on earth, and it's decreed as a fitting illustration of what will happen when God has created a new heaven and a new earth, it cannot be said that wearing gold is against God's decree!***  Further, why is it only women who are singled out regarding such things? Men can wear gold and jewellery too, you know! They can preen themselves to draw unwarranted attention to themselves, or to flaunt ostentatious wealth. That's just as obnoxious as women doing similarly, and is equally unfitting for Christian men as it is for Christian women.

Certainly modesty of dress and avoidance of flaunting oneself with jewellery and gold is detailed in the N.T. (as your two scripture texts show), but nowhere will you find it saying Christian women must never wear gold or jewellery!

Comment: I ve read that there is no word for jewelry in Bible so when they talk about jewelry they use word "gold " so that it is not only gold prohobited but all jewels..is that true?

Comment: @monique  The Hebrew scriptures use several words for 'jewel' such as 'chali' meaning ornament, and 'chelyay' as in Hosea 2:13, "She decked herself with her jewels". In many places 'keli' meaning vessel/instrument is used: "jewels of silver and jewels of gold", Gen.24:53. Also, "As a bride adorneth herself with her jewels" Isa.61:10. But there is no similar Greek word used in the N.T. as far as I can see.  Brides did not stick to 'just' silver or gold, you may be sure! Precious stones would be worked into silver or gold settings, which we call 'jewellery' Consider the ephod of the high

Comment: priest, with 12  precious stones, set into metal. They didn't have super-glue! But gold is not prohibited. It's the wrong use of it that matters. Besides, do Christians have to take off their wedding rings before worship? No, because gold in itself is not forbidden for us.

Answer (score 0):

Well it actually say that.. if you read orginal greek text u will see that women should wear respectable clothes with modesty and sound mind but not wear gold, pearls, very costy clothing or extravagant hairdos. It clearly says that. Also Peter says that our adorment shouldn't be putting on gold but good deeds. I love jewelry myself and it is hard to read but we cant unfortunaetly say it doesn't say anywhere in Bible.
I read early church fathers as tertulian, cyprian and clemens and they all speak against jewelry and they lived in same time as apostols. I am not saying they were right but I am pretty much living in fear because I don't wanna go to hell for that. I have been told that beofre and now I am freaking out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is no divine law against wearing gold and other adornments. It was done throughout the OT by righteous women and the scripture speaks positively of such ornaments in some cases.

- Rebekah wore bracelets and a nose ring of gold as a gift from her husband-to-be, Isaac. Gen. 24:3
- 2 Samuel 1:24 - Women of Israel, weep over Saul, who clothed you in scarlet and in finery, covered your clothing with ornaments of gold. (King David speaking)
- Song of Songs 1:11 - We will make pendants of gold for you, and ornaments of silver.
- Queen Esther saved her people by winning the king's favor, richly adorning herself to do so. She even wore the royal crown. (Esther 2:17)
- Isaiah 61:10 - He has covered me with the robe of righteousness, As a bridegroom decks himself with ornaments, and as a bride adorns herself with her jewels.
- Ezekiel 16:1 - I adorned you with jewelry, putting bracelets on your arms, a necklace about your neck.
- Jeremiah 31:4 - O virgin of Israel; thou shalt again be adorned with thy timbrels, and shalt go forth in the dances of them that make merry.

In the case of the NT, neither of the verses in question are phrased as laws. 1 Tim 2:8 says: "It is my wish..." or similar expressions, not "I command." Moreover, it deals with proper decorum in church assemblies, not in other situations. 1 Peter 3 gives advice to Christian women who are married to non-believers. They are to impress their husbands with their modesty, but are not commanded never to wear adornments, especially if their husbands want them to.  Both quotes emphasize the importance of internal beauty rather than external frills.

**Conclusion**: there is no divine law against wearing gold or other adornments. In fact the scripture often speaks positively of such things. The verses quoted in the OP both definitely prefer internal beauty over external trappings but they do not command believers not to wear jewelry, golden or otherwise.

Comment: I have been told that there was a lot of things allowed in OT because people have a hardened hearts like divorce etc but we should only look at new testament, what do u think about it?

Comment: "The Greek word for “I want” is boulomai. It is better understood as a combination of a desire with an implied command. Therefore, the word “likewise” refers us back to Paul’s command about how men are to worship. This helps us understand that Paul is going to tell women how they are to conduct themselves during the church service or in a Bible study".

Answer (score 0):

If a woman were to wear lots of jewelry and gold while she worships in the Church, she would distract her fellow brethren and make the focus on her when it should be on God. Wearing modest clothes made it so that the focus would be on God. Wearing jewelry was not forbidden , the idea behind it, the idea of self-centeredness and self-elevated.